# Solr full-import works in admin console, but not via URL

Tags: indexing, solr, import, lucene

I'm having trouble importing data from an Oracle DB into my Solr cores.

When I import via the Solr admin console it works fine.  But when I use the URL (`/solr/coreName/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=true&commit=true`), this is the result I get:

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">14</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="initArgs">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="config">./DIHconfig.xml</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <str name="command">full-import</str>
    <str name="status">idle</str>
    <str name="importResponse"/>
    <lst name="statusMessages">
        <str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">2</str>
        <str name="Total Rows Fetched">0</str>
        <str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
        <str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
        <str name="Full Dump Started">2017-06-29 14:44:35</str>
        <str name="">
            Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
        </str>
        <str name="Committed">2017-06-29 14:44:38</str>
        <str name="Time taken">0:0:8.564</str>
    </lst>
</response>
```

Note that the result is successful, it's just not finding any rows (but again, when I index via the GUI it works fine).

It's also worth mentioning that I currently have 4 cores in solr, but this issue is only occurring on two of them.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

**EDIT**

The issue appears to be resolved if I remove the following from where clause:

```
SELECT 
...
FROM 
...
WHERE '${dataimporter.request.clean}' != 'false'
...
```

Why does this evaluate to false when I import using the URL, but true when I use the admin console?

Comment: Have you tried to import via solr UI?  RequestHandler should be configured and available.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a connector between your Oracle server and Solr
Take a look at it : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55659_01/doc.31/e55984/oxh_ref006.htm#BDCUG860